# how to set min date (using datepicker android ) two years back from instant time or day

Tags: android

On one of my app I'm using  datepicker class to retrieve data form archive. 
 I need to set **Max and Min **.  On DatePicker.Dialog,
i was able to set **Max to the current time ** however, i counted do for **Min **. if someone to help me i really appreciate it. thanks in advance!

I am looking set **setMaxDate** = to current year
          and    **setMinDate** =  two years back from current year(current year -2)
NB: I triad to look  if this question was already answered. But, i couldn't get one. all that i see is **minData** = current time**dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());** which I am not looking for that. i want to set it to different year than the current.

here  below part of my code:

// On Clike for Floting button with + signe

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case imageButtonCalendar:
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            final int[] mYear = {c.get(Calendar.YEAR)};
            final int[] mMonth = {c.get(Calendar.MONTH)};
            final int[] mDay = {c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)};
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear[0] = year;
                    mMonth[0] = monthOfYear;
                    mDay[0] = dayOfMonth;

                    et.setText(new StringBuilder()
                            // to set date in editext
                            .append(mDay[0]).append("/").append(mMonth[0] + 1)
                            .append("/").append(mYear[0]).append(" "));
                }
            };
            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), pDateSetListener, mYear[0], mMonth[0], mDay[0]);

            dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime(),-year);

            dialog.show();

        break;
```

Comment: on a side note - what if someone changes the device time?

Comment: Just subtract 2 from your start year and use that for your `setMinDate(...)` call.

Comment: @Skynet: The minDate would still be 2 years earlier than the device time regardless of whether it was correct or not.

Comment: @Squonk I only meant correctness by that comment of mine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Calendar class :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
System.out.println("Date = "+ cal.getTime());
```

[Joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is the best Java library for Date.

Answer (score 0):

Get the date after subtracting 2 years :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -2);
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTime()); // set min date
```

Comment: Urrm, close but not right. The OP doesn't want a formatted String - they want to set a `DatePicker`.

Comment: Just use logic from above sample

Comment: thanks for ur reply! i have triad SimpleDataFormat.But, it didn't work for me since  I am using DatePicker. unless the is a way to implement  it. if there, is plz show me. thanks